# How to update the data of a certain field in text file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I currently have a text file called `equipment.txt` and there are some records in the text file. The format of the records are `StockCode|Manufacturer|Model|Description|SerialNo|Status` and the records are as follows:

```
S10000|HP|WM112|Wireless Mouse|11-2736-27371|Available
S10001|LOGITECH|GK2712|Gaming Keyboard|55-1662-28263|Available
S10002|DELL|GK1821|Wired Mouse|15-2541-66492|Available
S10003|LENOVO|SY1020|Keyboard|77-2661-46629|Available
S10004|PHILIPS|GN1822|Wireless Mouse|36-1638-49002|Available
S10005|HP|GV2612|Mousepad|17-2839-16392|Available
```

The system will allow the user to loan for the equipment. How to update the `status` of the equipment (ie. from `Available` to `On Loan`) in `equipment.txt` file after the user chooses to loan for an equipment (such as `S10001`), like what codes should I write?

**Edited:**
I have tried this code
`awk -F'|' -v id="${code^^}" 'BEGIN{ OFS="|" } $1 == code { found=1; $6="On Loan"}1' equipment.txt >> equipment.txt`, the `status` of `S10001` did change to `On Loan` but it append the same records again at the bottom of the text file, as shown below. How to make it not appending the same records but only change the `status` of that equipment only?

```
S10000|HP|WM112|Wireless Mouse|11-2736-27371|Available
S10001|LOGITECH|GK2712|Gaming Keyboard|55-1662-28263|Available
S10002|DELL|GK1821|Wired Mouse|15-2541-66492|Available
S10003|LENOVO|SY1020|Keyboard|77-2661-46629|Available
S10004|PHILIPS|GN1822|Wireless Mouse|36-1638-49002|Available
S10005|HP|GV2612|Mousepad|17-2839-16392|Available
S10000|HP|WM112|Wireless Mouse|11-2736-27371|Available
S10001|LOGITECH|GK2712|Gaming Keyboard|55-1662-28263|**On Loan**
S10002|DELL|GK1821|Wired Mouse|15-2541-66492|Available
S10003|LENOVO|SY1020|Keyboard|77-2661-46629|Available
S10004|PHILIPS|GN1822|Wireless Mouse|36-1638-49002|Available
S10005|HP|GV2612|Mousepad|17-2839-16392|Available
```

Comment: `sed` is likely the best for this https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: I would use an awk program for actually changing the status, and a bash wrapper to drive the awk program. From what you posted, we can't see at which point you are stuck. If you are searching for someone to write the complete code for you, this is the wrong forum to ask.

Comment: I have tried this `awk -F'|' -v id="${code^^}" '$1 == code { found=1; $6="On Loan"}1' equipment.txt >> equipment.txt` but when it prints out, the pipeline | has disappeared

Comment: In general `cmd file >> file` is a really bad idea.  The `>>` appends to the file instead of overwriting it.  `cmd file > file` is even worse, since all of the data will be erased before `cmd` tries to read it.  You need to review some basic shell tutorials.

Comment: To retain the `|` symbols, add `OFS='|'` to the awk invocation.

Comment: You really do not want to edit the file directly.  Any attempts to edit the file "in-place" will expose you to data corruption and data loss.  Use your awk to create a new file, then (if desired) rename the file.  The rename is atomic and can be delayed until you have verified that the data is correct.  (even if that just means ensuring that the process has completed without error).  If you attempt to edit the file directly and your process is terminated prematurely or encounters an error, your data may be lost.

Answer (score 1):

**sed** is your friend

`sed -e '/^S10001/s/Available/On Loan/' equipment.txt`

Will change the status for stock code S10001. Output is like this:

```
$ sed -e '/^S10001/s/Available/On Loan/' equipment.txt 
StockCode|Manufacturer|Model|Description|SerialNo|Status
S10000|HP|WM112|Wireless Mouse|11-2736-27371|Available
S10001|LOGITECH|GK2712|Gaming Keyboard|55-1662-28263|On Loan
S10002|DELL|GK1821|Wired Mouse|15-2541-66492|Available
S10003|LENOVO|SY1020|Keyboard|77-2661-46629|Available
S10004|PHILIPS|GN1822|Wireless Mouse|36-1638-49002|Available
S10005|HP|GV2612|Mousepad|17-2839-16392|Available
$
```

You could send output to a temporary file and then overwrite with it the content of original equipment.txt file.

Regards

Comment: What if the stock code `S10001` is user input?